# What happens if you run out of time?

Tags: paper-mario-the-thousand-year-door

In PM:TTYD, right after chapter 2 I think, there's a segment recalling the old Super Mario Bros, but where you play as Bowser

(If you don't know what I'm talking about, the Game Grumps just passed through that part, it starts at about 8 minutes in)

There is a timer going down, just like in the old days. They made the timer way to high, so it seems impossible to not finish the level in the allowed time.

But if you just stay there, and let that timer run out. What happens? Game over?

Comment: In the old days, letting the time expire meant you would lose a life and have to restart.  I'm assuming its the same thing.  A lot of the time, you would have a lot of time remaining in the "old days" as well.

Comment: What I'm assuming, since at the start of the level it shows bowser with infinite lives, is that the sequence will just restart. But there must be a joke or something in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I didn't tested this, I think that it will lead to dying and restarting the level. There are few more ways to die on those levels, including running into enemies and falling into lava (on last level).

> But there must be a joke or something in there.

Well, Bowser will say random reply ("Ready to roll!", etc.) each time you restart at level start screen. There are few of them and I find them pretty hilarious.

UPD: I checked this out, turned out I was 100% correct.

Comment: Dear downvoter, if you set your vote because my answer was a a guess, you can revoke it, as I tested it and it turned out to be a correct guess.